# The Freescale (NXP) S32V234 board, does not have ADC driver is provided.

Tags: linux, adc

The Freescale (NXP) S32V234 board, does not have ADC driver is provided.
Also on the document it does not seem to be described in detail.
Why is not there a more material or sample driver.
Please tell me someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [the NXP page](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/arm-processors/s32-arm-processors-microcontrollers/s32v230-family-of-processors-for-advanced-driver-assistance-systems:S32V230):

> The S32V230 family is designed to support computation-intensive applications for *image* processing.
>
> This is the first *automotive vision* system-on-chip (SoC) ...

I'm not convinced that DACs or ADCs  are necessary for its primary use case, especially since it apparently has some pretty awesome video processing stuff built in to the IPP and VP sections. We ourselves use digital/audio conversion on our NXP devices but that's mostly related to audio stuff.

As to the state of the documentation, there appears to be a fair bit available on that site linked to above, including drivers and so on. But it may well be that there's not a huge amount due to the large red text on the page:

> This page contains information on a preproduction product. Specifications and information herein are subject to change without notice.

And you're always free to start up a discussion on the NXP Community pages, there may well already be people who have gone before you.

Comment: It is said that the need for evaluation and operation verification.